# What is wrong with this Python code for finding an Armstrong number?

Tags: python-3.6

I'm trying to write a Python program that will return an Armstrong number and the resulting outputs do not meet my expectations. An Armstrong number in a given number base is a number that is the sum of its own digits each raised to the power of the number of digits.

```py
for i in range(0,len(lst)):
    lst[i] = int(lst[i])
sum2= 0

for i in range(0,len(lst)):
    sum1 = lst[i]*lst[i]*lst[i]
    sum2 += sum1
if sum2 == n :
    print("Armstrong number")
else:
    print("Not an Armstrong number")
```

Why is this code returning incorrect results?

Answer (score 1):

*You need to cast n as answered above!*

**Also Armstrong number is not just power of 3**

**The power is equal to number of digits present in the number.**

For Eg :

153 has 3 digits 1 5 and 3
so 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153

But if number is 4 digit Number then :

*Input :* 1634

*Output :* 1634 is an Armstrong Number

1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4 = 1634

and so on!

So basically the power is no. of digits present in the given no.

Here is my simple piece of code for it :

```
def Armstrong(num):
    exp = len(num)
    res = 0
    for i in num:
        res += pow(int(i),exp)
    if res == int(num):
        print(num + " is an Armstrong Number")
    else:
        print(num + " is not an Armstrong Number")
num=input("Enter a number : ")
Armstrong(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very, very close.  The only problem is that `n` is a string, not an int, so when you compare it to `sum2` it will never be equivalent.  Cast `n` to an int and problem solved:

```
if sum2 == int(n):
```

If you want to see a more streamlined way to get the same result, here is an example:

```
value_string = input("Enter an integer value: ")

starting_value = int(value_string)
digits = [int(char) for char in value_string]

cubed_sum = sum([
    one_digit ** 3
    for one_digit in digits
])

if cubed_sum == starting_value:
    print(f"{starting_value} is an Armstrong number.")
else:
    print(f"{starting_value} is not an Armstrong number.")
```